# How to setup Laravel Websocket

Tags: docker, laravel-5, websocket, socket.io, vuejs2

I just joined a team with Laravel Project and assigned to setup the websocket because I have an experience with it. But their project is kinda weird because they have separate setup in frontend and backend. The frontend is installed via vue-cli and then created another laravel project and use Laravel Passport to provide an API to connect to the frontend.

This kind of setup is very new to me and I don't have idea to set it up.

How can I setup the websocket in this project? Do I need to setup the laravel echo to both frontend and backend?

By the way, we used `docker` on both projects. Thanks!

Comment: Using Pusher? Or are you trying to roll your own websocket implementation?

Comment: not pusher, I have tried to use docker's laravel-echo-server container on my other projects but this one is way more different because they have separate setup

Comment: Echo is the javascript package, that gets installed on the Frontend instance of laravel. But what are you using as the broadcaster? Just redis?

Comment: yes just redis.. I think I got it working now .. I'm having another problem. It returned 500 Error code when I add `event()` in the controller. It will work if I remove it

Comment: Separate question probably.